# Read correctly a value which includes the file's delimiter

Tags: talend

I have a column which suppose to take the value: hello, Ted

But because the delimiter of the file is "," it separates the sentence into two columns.

column1: hello

column2: Ted

How can I output the: hello, Ted?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file with "tFileInputRow" first as line by line, and "look and replace" for each line for the comma with space (", ") and replace it with space only (" ") using a piece of Java code inside "tJavaRow". After that try to extract the fields based on the desired schema using tExtractFields component and move on as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Your source data needs to redefined and have the data in Text enclosure with "". Once that is set you can handle by enabling CSV option in basic setting of `tFileInputDelimited`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Although, the format of the source can not be modified.

Comment: @Thkas - then I have to ask how do you think the system will identify the comma (,) which is part of data or part of delimiter?

Comment: You are right. I was wondering if there is something that can help our pipeline to understand where to read the comma as a character. Thank you very much. Appreciate your answer.